# Unregister Broadcast Receiver using another Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I am working on an android app in which I am registering `Broadcast Receiver` in one of the `activity`.

**Problem**

Lets assume that activity name is `MyActivity` and the `Broadcast Receiver` I register in this activity is `myReceiver`.

I want to unregister `myReceiver` from another `Broadcast Receiver`'s, lets call it `secondReceiver`, `onReceive` method. I have a method, lets call it `myMethod`, to unregister the `myReceiver` inside `myActivity` activity.

When I call this `myMethod` from inside the `secondReceiver`, I get the `IntentReceiverLeaked` exception.

**Question**

How can I unregister `Broadcast Receiver` from another `Broadcast Receiver`?

Comment: Try to register/unregister the BroadcastReceiver with application Context instead

Comment: @Demonick it works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to run your unregister method which is `myMethod` from another activity instance is to register a broadcast receiver on your `myActivity` with a **custom action** of your own, and in the `onReceive` method you call `myMethod` to unregister your reciever. Then you just need to **send a broadcast** with your declared action when you want to unregister the receiver . This way there won't be any leak due to not maintaining a reference to `myActivity`.

Here's a demonstration:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String ACTION_UNREGISTER = "com.yourDomain.subDomain.UNREGISTER_RECEIVER";
    private BroadcastReceiver mUnregisteringReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            myMethod();
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        registerReceiver(mUnregisteringReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_UNREGISTER));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        ...
        unregisterReceiver(mUnregisteringReceiver);
    }
}
```

Comment: what If `MyActivity` is destroyed? Then `mUnregisteringReceiver` will get unregistered and `myMethod` won't be called and hence the intent leak exception.

Comment: @Nick the proper way of registering a context-registered receiver on your activity is to unregister it when it gets destroyed, because context-registered receivers are bound to activity lifetime and by unregistering it you make sure no leak will occur, as [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers) says. The only case that would apply here is that you want to unregister your receiver **before** the activity gets destroyed to prevent receiving further broadcasts which in that case your activity is still alive.

Comment: actually, I am downloading a file from server in background using Intent service, I want to be able to download and execute some code when download completes even when activity is destroyed.

Comment: In that case you should use Android [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) passing your activity class with some extras you need; which is designed for the exact use you need. In simple words it keeps a pending context to your component and runs it the moment you need it (end of download) which will open your activity while passing the extras so it can handle the proper action you need. A simple example would be when you click on a notification and your activity gets opened.